# Platform for an Access 2007 DB that may import Excel and will require reports

Tags: winforms, ms-access

Doing an application that will use Access as a back end and will rely on importing Excel sheets. Lots of reporting as well.

The app will only be used by one or two people.

Would you build this in Access forms? I also know Winforms and C#.

What criteria would you use for your decision making? Why would you choose one approach over another? What more information would you need to make a decision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When considering an Access solution, the number of people using the application is an issue about data storage and retrieval.  The front-end pieces should be segregated into a separate db file, and each user should have their own copy of that front-end db file; the back-end db file contains only data.  You should view that type of split as an absolute requirement if there is any possibility that more than one user will ever use the application at the same time.

If a split Access application is unacceptable, use something other than Access for the front-end part.

As far as the suitability of Access for the front-end, you haven't described any features which could not be quickly and easily implemented with Access features.  Notice you didn't provide any details about the purpose of the forms.  For all we know, they may be used only to drive imports from Excel and select among reports, perhaps with form fields to select criteria for those reports.  If that's all you need, it is an almost trivial task in Access.

Comment: That's a fair answer. They currently use Excel for an everything cut-and-paste solution and receive data in that format, so likely I'll be just bolting on some features to keep permanent data records for them and help them get better imports.

Comment: OK, sounds to me like that could be achieved easily with Access.  So in answer to the question about Access vs. Winforms and C#, I would choose Access ... especially because I know Access but would have to learn how to use Winforms and C#.  That's probably not a very useful response for you, though.  :-)

Comment: Very useful actually. In the past I had determined to use Visual Basic 6 over Access and the sheer amount of work I had to do to simply get data out and report on it was overwhelming compared to what I could have done simply with the report tools that come with Access.